# Read pcap using scapy (DNS queries)

Tags: python, pcap, scapy

```
dnsPackets = rdpcap(dnsPcap)
domain = 'stackoverflow.com'

for packet in dnsPackets:
    if packet.haslayer(DNSQR):
        query = packet[DNSQR].qname
        if domain in query:
            outFile.write(query + '\n')
```

This code gives me a nice list of DNS queries containing the domain stackoverflow.com.
However, comparing the results in wireshark i can see that i have 1 more query, and that query is in a malformed packet (wireshark reads it fine). How would i go extracting that as well?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what is shown in Wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved. Above code was correct but bug in code later on.